# Swift: Re-activating Tap Gesture on Disclosure Indicators

Tags: swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a Swift project that has a Table View Controller with multiple Static Cell Sections. Some cells have UITextFields and others have Accessory: Disclosure Indicators. I’ve implemented the following Swift code to dismiss the keyboard when the background is tapped:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("hideKeyboard"))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func hideKeyboard() {
    tableView.endEditing(true)
}
```

This works great for releasing the keyboard on tapping the background, but it also removed the tap gesture for the Disclosure Indicators (swipe still works). Does anyone know how to re-activate the tap gesture for the Disclosure Indicators cells after implementing this hideKeyboard() function?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the gesture recognizer and remove it from the view when you hide the keyboard.

```
class YourController: UITableViewController {
    let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
      let tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideKeyboard")
      tg.cancelsTouchesInView = true
      return tg
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func hideKeyboard() {
        tableView.endEditing(true)
        tableView.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
}
```

Comment: While implementing the solution, I did receive a build error on the “let tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: “hideKeyboard”)” line. The error read: Cannot find an initializer for type ‘UITapGestureRecognizer’ that accepts an…bleViewController -> () -> SpecificationsTableViewController, action: String)’. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated!